# how to switch between view inside the uitabbarcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am working with `UITabBarcontroller`, where i want to switch between view  s      with an `UISegmentController`, but the `UITabBarItem` should not be hidden when I click on `UISegmentController`:

```
if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
{
//            UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//            UITabBarController *wc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@""];
//            [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];            

}
else if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
{
   UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UITabBarController *wc = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
}
```

[image: This is the image with uisegmentcontroller]

[image: This is the structure is used using container view]

Comment: Someone please help me i am trying this last four days but not getting any ides.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that what you are trying to do is have a secondary tab bar (the segment control) to switch between views inside a primary tab. In this case, I would suggest to use a view container, and make the switch inside it. Something like this: [image]

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but i think containor view will not work for me, because  when view change i have lots of uitextfield and button so i need to use uiscrollview and if i will use container view how will i implement different scrollview for two view controllers.

Comment: Within a container view, you embed a view with its own view controller. In practice, you instantiate the view controller (the one on the far right in my picture) and embed its view in the container view. In this way, it's like you have a full separate view controller inside a box.

Comment: if i add a scrollview in the instantiate view, is it work perfectly?. Actually i tried it before but it was not working.

Comment: See the second picture in my answer. I just tried that and I get a table view with all its view controller embedded in the container view. You have to use the embed segue to do this, and the same when you switch views programmatically through the segment control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
But once it changes in The TabBarController,your current VC changes and you cannot access the SegmentedControl as you are in a new VC now, thus you have to again navigate to the older VC via the Tabbar. But you can try this.

```
if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    [self.navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
else {
    [self.navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

This code would work when your storyboard is like this
[image]